# Unable to recognize hard disks in 16.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, 16.04, hard-drive, disk

I opened my desktop box and I saw 2 physical hard disks.

In `Disks` I can see `/sda` and `/sdb`,

[image: Hard Disk ST]

and

[image: Hard Disk WD]

but cannot access them or format them.

If I try to format them, I got this error:

> Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sda"' exited with
>   non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sda: probing
>   initialization failed: Device or resource busy  (udisks-error-quark,
>   0)

Strangely the master system disk is an additional one as this
[image: System Disk]

By `$ df -h`, we can see

```
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 1.6G  158M  1.5G  10% /run
/dev/mapper/isw_eacbecjdda_Volume1p2  910G  293G  599G  33% /
tmpfs                                 7.9G   93M  7.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs                                 100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                                 1.6G  156K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Only one 1TB disk is present, the system disk `/dev/dm-0`.

What's wrong with my system?

Comment: Why do you think anything is "wrong" with your system? is something not working? It looks like sda and sdb are configured as a single 1TB RAID volume (called dm-0), on which a 992GB Ext4 filesystem was created for your root filesystem.

Comment: @steeldriver I have two 1TB disks. But only 1T is available in the system.

Comment: The two disks appear to be configured together to form an Intel RST RAID mirror

Comment: it appears so but strangely 1TB is missing.... Ubuntu ate it......

Comment: This is RAID. The data is stored on both disks. It is suppoesed to work this way.

Comment: @Pilot6 but why there is 1BT missing :-(?

Comment: It is not missing. You can google what RAID is and you will find out why two disks of 1TB are shown as 1TB total.

Comment: I found `raid 1`, raid mirror... reading is faster at the cost of reduce half of space, onz.....